# How do I pick the location where Gnucash backs up to?

Tags: gnucash

I would like to back up Gnucash to a external hard drive.  Latest Gnucash version and latest Mac OS 10.12.6.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a tech support question, not a personal finance discussion

Comment: @NathanL Please see [Should questions on the technical usage of a financial management tool be on-topic, or off-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997) on meta.

Comment: @BenMiller this specific case is not about how to use the tool to manage finances. If it were a question about how to record a particular type of transaction or was otherwise finance related, I would agree, but in this case, it is about backing up computer files, which is not a personal finance topic.

Comment: @NathanL I think that meta question is specifically addressing your concern ("technical usage").

Comment: @BenMiller we can agree to disagree on this one. As we often do.

Comment: @NathanL Agreed. :)

Answer (score 1):

To backup the actual application: Copy it from the Applications folder to the backup location.

To backup your ledger: Open you ledger, then select 'save as' and save it to a different location.  Make sure when you open it again, you explicitly go to 'open' and open the non-backed up version or Gnucash will pick the last saved file to open (the backed up version).  Alternatively, you can just copy the files and logs from the original directory to a backup location.

Comment: Thank you Andy,I appreciate your time and effort.....Pete